# How to force symfony route to have xml extension?

Tags: xml, symfony, rss, symfony-1.2

Our client is using **Symfony 1.2** in his website. He requested to create XML RSS Feeds page for his blog post. I did created the RSS feeds but the problem is with the route! I want the route to be **rss.xml** but now the route is /rss only. How can i force it to load the feeds on **/rss.xml** route i.e with xml extension

**Routing**:

```
blog_rss:
  url:   /rss
  param: {module: blog, action: rss, sf_format: xml}
```

I also created an action

```
 public function executeRss(sfWebRequest $request) { }
```

And template

```
templates\rssSuccess.xml.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony 1.2 is severly outdated... but anyways: just extend the route definition:

```
blog_rss:
  url:   /rss.xml
  param: {module: blog, action: rss, sf_format: xml}
```

Comment: i did the same for sitemap.xml but it throws this error `Action "rss/index" does not exist.` any idea?